# How to disable part of javascript script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is it possible to only execute some lines of javascript file that website downloads? I want to be able to skip some lines while executing others.

Comment: Let me see if I undestand, you want to download a script file but execute only a part of it instead of the entire code? do you know what lines you want to reduce up ahead?

Comment: Is it your own script, or a third-party script? There's no common skip method, you've to hardcode skips.

Comment: You could use a proxy that intercepted the script and changed the content

Comment: @Teemu Let's assume the hardest scenerio where the file is 3rd party minified file so whole code is in one line but I found the part I want to disable.

Comment: @mplungjan Do you know any software that would be usfeul for this kind of interception?

Comment: No. That would likely have to be hand crafted, but since you have not given any details it is hard to say. As it is your question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at SO.